# PAM configuration popup yes or no for answer? after sudo apt install software-properties-common

Tags: linux, php, pam

I was trying to install the latest php version and after a command not found I googled it and they say to use the following command ''sudo apt install software-properties-common''
After doing this I get a pam configuration popup with this message :

One or more of the files /etc/pam.d/common- {auth,account,password,session} have been locally modified. Please indicate whether these local changes should be overridden using the system-provided configuration. If you decline this option, you will need to manage your system's authentication configuration by hand.

override local changes to /etc/pam.d/common-*?

I am stuck and don't know what to answer, I have googled it for an hour without success!
[image]

Comment: I'm stuck here too. This is painful.